# When testing a method call that I know happens , I get a failure error stating the method was called 0 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a controller that calls the CSVCreator class when a get request is made. People is just a list of Persons that have some basic values like name and title.

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data CSVCreator.new(people).create }
end
```

My CSVCreator looks like this

```
class CSVCreator 

  HEADERS = ["Name", "Date", "Title"].freeze

  def initialize(people)
      @people = people
  end

  def generate
      CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << HEADERS
        @people.each do |person|
          row = [person.name, person.date, person.title] 
          csv << row
        end
      end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to figure out how I would go about testing this in Rspec? What I've tried is

```
it "calls CSVCreator when get request is made" do
   csv_creator = double("CSVCreator")
   people = double("People")
   
   allow(csv_creator).to receive(:new).with(people)
   allow(csv_creator).to receive(:create)
   
   expect(csv_creator).to receive(:new).with(people)
   expect(csv_creator).to receive(:create)

   get :index, format: :csv
end
```

My thought process was to decouple the controller and the CSVCreator and People classes. So to test the controller, I wanted to see if it correctly calls the methods it needs to, so I created test doubles for those objects. I'm new to RSpec and testing in general, so please let me know if my approach was incorrect.

My issue is, I get a failure saying

```
     Failure/Error: expect(csv_creator).to receive(:new).with(people)
 
   (Double "CSVCreator").new(#<Double "People">)
       expected: 1 time with arguments: (#<Double "People">)
       received: 0 times
```

I know my class works and it creates the CSV, and that `CSVCreator.new(people).create` being called in the controller. So I'm curious as to why I'm receiving this failure.

Answer (score 1):

i guess that the input param `people` is created somewhere in your controller, but i'm sure it's not your double "People", you have to stub the method `:new` of the People class to return an `instance_double` of "People", Or in case you want to make sure that CSVCreator is created with a special "People", for example in your controller you call this to get people: `PeopleService.some_logic(..) -> a_special_people`, then stub that method `allow(PeopleService).to receive(:some_logic).and_return(instance_double_people)`

beside that, you could also create an `instance_double` of CSVCreator instead, then stub method `:new` of CSVCreator to return that instance_double, now you only need to verify that instance_double has called `:create` method since it makes sure that CSVCreator has called `:new` and the new instance of CSVCreator has called `:create`.

```rb
it "calls CSVCreator when get request is made" do
   csv_creator = instance_double(CSVCreator)
   people = instance_double(People)

   allow(People).to receive(:new).and_return(people)
   # allow(PeopleService).to receive(:some_logic).and_return(people)
   allow(CSVCreator).to receive(:new).with(people).and_return(csv_creator)
   allow(csv_creator).to receive(:create)
   
   get :index, format: :csv
   
   expect(csv_creator).to have_received(:create)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class method on your `CSVCreator` that creates an instance and calls the generate method:

```rb
class CSVCreator 
  # ...
  def self.perform(people)
    new(people).generate
  end
end
```

```rb
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data CSVCreator.perform(people) }
  end
end
```

This creates a better API so that consumers don't have to have as much knowledge about the class and it makes it way easier to set expectations:

```rb
it "calls CSVCreator when get request is made" do
   expect(CSVCreator).to receive(:perform)
   get :index, format: :csv
end
```

However stubbing in `people` is a bit more problematic and depends on how its actually implemented. If its a method on the controller it would be hard to stub without using `any_instance` which is a code smell.